# Why isn't the LayoutUpdated event fired when the layout is updated? WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

My question reagrds the LayoutUpdated event of the a panorama item. 
It doesn't matter which item I assign the LayoutUpdated event to, it will not fire when I scroll through the items. Here is my code:

```xml
<controls:Panorama Grid.Row="2" x:Name="WebScrollView" >
    <!--Panorama item one-->
    <controls:PanoramaItem Width="480" x:Name="LeftPanoramaControl"/>

    <!--Panorama item two-->
    <controls:PanoramaItem Width="480" x:Name="MiddlePanoramaControl"/>
    <controls:PanoramaItem Width="480" x:Name="RightPanoramaControl"/>
</controls:Panorama>
```

In my C# class, I say:

```cs
private void BrowsersLoaded( )
{
    //first, we stop the progressbar
    AnimatedProgressBar.StopProgressBar( );

    //next, we want to make sure that the left and right browser are going to load new content, as now, for instance, the left browser is placed upon the middlecontent
    //so, we cannot just say _leftBrowser.Navigate, this will screw up the view
    LeftPanoramaControl.Visibility   = _leftControlVisibility;
    RightPanoramaControl.Visibility  = _rightControlVisibility;

    WebScrollView.UpdateLayout( );
    WebScrollView.DefaultItem = MiddlePanoramaControl;                                   
    //this seems like beating around the bush, doesm't it? 
    //well, A problem I encountered was that the LayoutUpdated event was called even before I could do anything, check whatever boolean, cause they were all
    //set to true even before the event was fired, which called upon the CheckID method, and gave a huge infinite loop. 

    MiddlePanoramaControl.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler( WebScrollView_LayoutUpdated );
}
```

But it will not fire when I scroll through the panorama items. 
Does anyone have any idea why?

greetz, Geekpeek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx):

> Occurs when the layout of the various visual elements associated with
>   the current Dispatcher changes.

As you have observed, the `LayoutUpdated` event can be handled on any UI element, and will produce the same result regardless of which element you use to handle this event. Note also the `sender` argument is alawys null.

Now, why does it not fire when you scroll through panorama items? The `LayoutUpdated` event fires whenever the Silverlight framework performs a layout pass, i.e. it calculate the positions of each UI element based on the visual tree and the characteristics of the various panels and elements within the tree.

Just because you see something move on your phone screen, does not mean that a layout pass has occurred. Animations that set `RenderTransforms` will not result in the layout changing.

Layout is expensive, so I would expect that the panorama control has been designed in such a way that each item has its layout determined before you start scrolling through items.

Why not handle the [Panorama.SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectionchanged%28VS.92%29.aspx) event instead?